# Prestashop 1.6.0.9 multishop, filter admin products by status

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Faced some trouble within prestashop 1.6.0.9 admin products filtering by status in multishop enabled.

To explain in details picture below 
[image]

As seen in picture product filtered by status "NO", but it displays on. Does anynone has such issue, by looking at [controller](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/controllers/admin/AdminProductsController.php) and database, status is filtered by product table - where product is off, but displays from product_shop table where that shop active field is on. How can i manage filtering by status, am i facing with this alone? is there a fix already to this (HelperList?).

Can i somehow to set that list would be filtered by joint tables?

```
$this->table = 'product';

$this->fields_list['active'] = array(
    'title' => $this->l('Status'),
    'active' => 'status',
    'filter_key' => $alias.'!active',
    'align' => 'text-center',
    'type' => 'bool',
    'class' => 'fixed-width-sm',
    'orderby' => false
);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use `['list'] => $this->countries_array` as option in your field list see documentation here http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+HelperList+class

Comment: thanks for answer, but 'list' doesnt solve filtering issue as it provides data to selections just